# IntelliJ console not monospaced in Windows

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to print a chess board in the console, using the piece's unicode chars. On my Linux system it works great in the integrated intelliJ-console with my console font set to "Source Code Pro", but if I try to print the same output on a Windows machine, the chess characters are much wider than all other characters.

Here's how it looks on my linux machine:

[image: The board on Linux]

And this is how it looks on Windows machines (I have tried two independent machines so far):

[image: The board on Windows]

How do I fix the widths of the unicode characters? The font is the same across all machines, Windows or Linux, Source Code Pro.
Here's a screenshot of the Console Font settings:

[image: Console Font settings on Windows]

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

Here's the text output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h 
8  ♜  ♘  ♝  ♕  ♚  ♗  ♞  ♖  8
7  ♙  ♟  ♙  ♟  ♙  ♟  ♙  ♟  7
6                          6
5                          5
4                          4
3                          3
2  ♙  ♟  ♙  ♟  ♙  ♟  ♙  ♟  2
1  ♜  ♘  ♝  ♕  ♚  ♗  ♞  ♖  1
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h
```